# SNORT logs data into MySQL PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, networking, snort

Is there any possible ways that i can make SNORT to insert all of its logs into PhpMyAdmin using MySQL?.

And if it does, Is there any way that i can call all of these data like Source IP, destionation IP, Port, Timestamp and message based on preset SNORT rules?

Thank You

Comment: You can use a barnyard2. Refer to https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/000/122/original/Snort_2.9.9.x_on_Ubuntu_14-16.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA%2F20180309%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180309T152833Z&X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=88e2cfbdfa81c790097e1494cf78e0ded0d3d9dcb12d873340342fd06c8447e3

Comment: the link is empty sir, can you please repost?

Comment: I don't know why the link is empty.:) Repost https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/000/122/original/Snort_2.9.9.x_on_Ubuntu_14-16.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA%2F20180316%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180316T013508Z&X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=e9cdaf17159a92b4f6c2bfe33fb611bd825352f2ccc4192f1ab9a94946c81f7d

Comment: This is my install script on centos 7. I hope this helps you.  http://kangmyounghun.blogspot.kr/2018/01/centos7-mysql7-snort.html